# i embedded spotify in iframe but the songs are only playing for 30 second

Tags: html, spotify

i embedded spotify in iframe but the songs are only playing for 30 second. I also want to custom the display design and color. I actually want only the songs to play from a playlist, no cover image. here is my code-

```
type here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/0pcO7CAyLTvutjY1PKj1Vp?utm_source=generator" width="100%" height="152" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy">

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the background color and also playing. but the songs are showing for preview. the text color or the playlist image can not be moved.

Comment: See [Troubleshooting documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/embeds/tutorials/troubleshooting).